# RSA Public key System

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In RSA public key system, how does one ensure that the receiver is getting the message from the intended sender? How can the receiver rule out messages from eavesdroppers

I know that the receiver has his private key and can decode messages sent by anyone to him, but how does he ensure that he has the message from the intended source. Is there a way, by which he can reject other messages, without decoding it, and only decode the message coming from the intended source?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm) shows a worked example. Regards

Answer (score 2):

If the sender encodes the message both with the receiver's public key and the sender's private key, then the deconding succeeds only by means of the receiver's  private key (thus ensuring nobody else can read it) and the sender's public key (thus ensuring the sender's private key was used in sending, i.e. nobody else could have encoded the message).

One can avoid decoding the *complete* message as the signature part need only encode a small portion of the message (e.g. a good hash)

Comment: can you include a short example, you dont need to compute, but just give an illustration when you find time?

Comment: Well suppose there are 3 people who send me messages using my public key, how would i make sure i only read the message i am supposed to, i will be able to decode all the messages, but how do i make sure to ignore the remaining two?

Comment: I understand that if the sender uses his private key, and my public key, then i can know that nobody else encoded the message, but this is with the prior knowledge who the sender is, in which case there is no problem.  But further suppose that i am expecting a message from sender A. I use my private key and sender A's public key to decrypt the message, but suppose Sender B(intruder) also sends a message, i still use my private key and sender A's public key to decrypt, but what is the guarantee that in this case the message wont make sense and hence i can ignore it?